# UI does not display tags of a column (data type: text)

Tags: jquery, mysql, tags

Wondering why my string column (`message_template`) does not let any words encased in tags `<>` to show up in the interface. The data type is simply text.

**SQL:**

[image: 1]

**UI:** (please ignore the random letters, this is a test table)

[image: 2]

**JS Code:**

```
$.each(response.all_messages, function (key, message) {
    tbody+='<tr>'+
        '<td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">'+message.message_name+'</p>'+message.message_description+'</td>'+
        // '<td>'+gettemplatetype(message.template_type)+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+message.message_type+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+message.message_template+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+getreplytype(message.reply, message.reply_type, message.reply_description)+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+getmessagestatus(message.effective_start_datetime, message.effective_end_datetime)+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+
            '<button type="button" value="'+message.id+'" class="edit_message btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button> '+
            '<button type="button" value="'+message.message_id+'" class="delete_message btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>'+
        '</td>'+
        '</tr>';
});
```

the specific line for the column `message_template` is:

```
'<td>'+message.message_template+'</td>'+
```

Comment: Because `<` and `>` indicate an html tag, which the browser is attempting to render for you because you're using string concatenation to build an html string.   I hope none of your DB text is entered by the user...   enter name:  `<script>location.href="stackoverflow.com"</script>`.   User: *why does the list keep opening on stack overflow*?

Comment: Try `'<td>'+escape(message.messasge_type)+'</td>'`... though [MDN escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) suggests this shouldn't be used - unclear of the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simply (replace regex method) and replace your line with this line:

```
  '<td>'+ message.message_template.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"") +'</td>'+
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion, but somehow the tags are not showing up

Comment: you want to display tags too in frontent?

Comment: yes basically i just need to convert the tags into string

Comment: can you give an example of your display, I mean how do you want to convert `<>` tags to string?

Comment: just to not have them read as an html tag but a string